# Comparing numbers brought from ftp servers

Tags: python, file, ftp

I have some code like this:

```
def checkupdate():
    build_version = 1.8

    server = 'server ip'
    ftp2 = ftplib.FTP(server)
    ftp2.login()
    writeversion = open("latest_version.txt", "w")
    ftp2.retrlines('RETR latest_version.txt', writeversion.write())

    writeversion.write(latestversion)
    writeversion.close()
    latestversion2 = open("latest_version.txt", "r")
    latestversion3 = latestversion2.readline()

    if latestversion3 > build_version:
        tkMessageBox.showwarning("Updater", "There is a new version. Please check our site.")
elif latestversion3 == build_version:
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Updater", "Current version:%d, is the latest." % build_version)
else:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Updater", "Current version:%d is the latest." % build_version)

    latestversion2.close()
    os.unlink("latest_version.txt")
```

However, everytime i run this, it cant write the version fetched from the ftp server to latest_version.txt, and the file is empty. It also tells me that there is **always** a new version. Any way to get this piece to work?

Comment: can you fix your indentation please?

Comment: Some part still is not fixed? (the if/elif/else part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing different types here.  `build_version` is considered as a `float` and `latestversion3` as a `string`.  As such, what you're observing is perfectly expected:

```
>>> "1.6" > 1.7
True
>>> "0.42" > 1.7
True
```

One fix would be to declare as a *string*:

```
build_version = "1.8"
```

However, you might run into problems if you try to compare version numbers such as `1.7.1` and `1.7.10`.  You should be using [`disutils.version`](http://docs.python.org/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.version) in order to compare version numbers.